# Recording of Vishnu Sahasranamam

Tags: krishna, bhishma, vishnu-sahasranama

When Bheeshma was glorifying Krishna with Sahasranamam everyone was looking at him including Krishna and Vyasa. The first to react was Yudhistirar. He said, ‘Pithamaha has chanted 1000 glorious names of Vasudeva. All of us listened but none of us have noted it down. The sequence is lost’. Then all turned to Krishna and asked for His help. As usual He said, ‘I also was listening like the rest of you. What can we do?’
Who recorded the Vishnu sahasranama and thru which mode?

Comment: If the answer is supposed to be some sphatika which Sahadeva possessed, I seriously doubt that story.

Comment: @surya--you are right. It was told by Kanchi Periava himself.

Comment: @Surya--In that case you can justify how we got Vishnu Sahasranama.When Mahans like Kanchi periavar is telling we ordinary humans should not doubt.

Comment: But it is not mentioned in Mahabharata. Also Bhagavan Vedavyasa is in their midst and he doesn't need a tape to remember the Vishnu Sahasranamam, given that he arranged the Vedas and Puranas by himself. I also am not sure whether Kanchi Periyava actually said this.

Comment: @Surya--Will post the answer right now.

Answer (score 1):

> Only HE can give this kind of explanation. Read the power of Sapdika…….
>   Once  way back in 1940s or 50s someone was interviewing Maha Periyavaar. That gentleman recorded the interview using a tape recorder. Periyavaa then posed a question.
>   “Does anyone know which is the oldest known tape recorder?”
>   Nobody was able to answer. Then Maha Periyavaa asked another question.
>   “How did Vishnu Sahasranamam comes to us?”
>   Someone said Bheeshma gave it to us.
>   All agreed. Then Maha Periyavaa posed another query .
>   “When all were listening to Bheeshma on the battlefield, who took notes at Kurukshetra?”
>   Again silence.
>   Maha Periyavaar explained…
>   When Bheeshma was glorifying Krishna with Sahasranamam Everyone was looking at him including Krishna and Vyasa. After he finished the 1000 Namas all opened their eyes. The first to react was Yudhistirar. He said, ‘Pithamaha has chanted 1000 glorious names of Vasudeva. All of us listened but none of us have noted it down. The sequence is lost’. Then all turned to Krishna and asked for His help. As usual He said, ‘I also was listening like the rest of you. What can we do?’
>   Then all beseeched Krishna to help them recover the precious rendition. Then Krishna said, ‘It can only be done by Sahadeva and Vyasa will write it down.’
>   Everyone wanted to know how Sahadeva could do it. Krishna replied, ‘Sahadeva is the only one amongst us wearing SUTHA SPATIKAM. If he prays to Shiva and does dhyanam he can convert the SPATIKA into waves of sound and Vyasa can write it down. Then, both Sahadeva and Vyasa, sat in the same place, under Bheeshma, where he had recited the Sahasranamam. Sahadeva started the dhyanam to recover the sound waves from the Spatika.
>   The nature of Spatika is that it will capture sounds in a calm environment which can be got back with proper dhyanam of Maheswara who is Swethambara and SPATIKA. So, the world’s earliest tape recorder is this SPATIKA which gave us the wonderful Vishnu Sahasranama.  when Maha Periyavaar explained this all were stunned… From the Spatika recording, the grantha came to us thru Vyasa.

**Source---My friend who is an ardent devotee of Maha Periava sent the above thru mail**.

Comment: It is very nice to share the incident about Maha Periava. But, It would be better  to support the story with an  appropriate source.

Comment: @Ganesh--My friend send me the mail. Probably it might be from mahaperiavawordpress.com

Comment: You should try to find the source of the mail your friend sent and then post it as an answer, e.g., if it's from a Purana then post the relevant chapter here. You shouldn't simply post forwarded e-mails and Facebook posts as answers here. From [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/94/2995) answer on meta: **People who are frustrated with Wikipedia and other blogs, sites, etc should be able to come here for expert, lucidly explained, and extremely well researched knowledge complete with full, reliable references and sources.**